# debugging stripped-down linux system

Tags: gdb

I'm having a problem on my embedded linux board. My program runs, then somewhere in a particular function throws a segmentation fault. So i'm trying to track down why this is happening so I can fix it.

The problem is that my target board runs a filesystem image which does not include gdb or gdbserver. Is there any way I can debug this application as it runs on the embedded target without rebuilding the kernel or my application?

Comment: Can you copy the correct cross-compiled gdbserver to your board?  Failing that, does your program dump a corefile?  Can you collect that corefile and debug with the correct cross-compiled GDB on your development machine?

Comment: Also note that gdb or gdbserver have *nothing* to do with your kernel build.

Comment: @Employed Russian Yes, sorry, I meant filesystem image - corrected.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'll have to try it and come back.